# Trying to clone a repository but the line endings are wrong

Tags: git, cygwin, msysgit

I have cygwin and msysgit on my computer.  I am trying to clone a repository for a vim package with this command:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax.git
```

However, when I run vim, it fails, reporting error `E488: Trailing characters`.  This appears to be cause by the line endings being `CRLF` rather than just `LF`, which is confirmed when I replace them.

Of course replacing them manually isn't what I want.  I'd rather have git do it for me.  However, as I am using my computer for developing on the Windows platform, I don't want to modify any global settings.

Is there a command line switch to have git clone a repo using `LF` `EOLs` only?

Comment: Can someone help me improve my Q & A?  I don't understand why I got downvoted.

Comment: Looks like it was just a driveby downvoting.  I don't see anything wrong.  Only mods were just some minor formatting changes.

Answer (score 30):

Ok, so it turns out that a config key can be set at the command line using the `-c` switch.  That would change my command to:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone -c core.autocrlf=false https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax.git
```

From [git clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---configltkeygtltvaluegt) help:

> **--config <key>=<value>**
> **-c <key>=<value>**
>
>   Set a configuration variable in the newly-created repository; this takes effect immediately after the repository is initialized, but before the remote history is fetched or any files checked out. The key is in the same format as expected by
>   [git-config[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)
>   (e.g.,
>   `core.eol=true`
>   ). If multiple values are given for the same key, each value will be written to the config file. This makes it safe, for example, to add additional fetch refspecs to the origin remote.

and [git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coreautocrlf) help:

> **core.autocrlf**
>
>   Setting this variable to "true" is the same as setting the
>   `text`
>   attribute to "auto" on all files and core.eol to "crlf". Set to true if you want to have
>   `CRLF`
>   line endings in your working directory and the repository has LF line endings. This variable can be set to input, in which case no output conversion is performed.

I've verified that this fixes the issue.

Comment: Don't know why this got downvoted, it's the right answer.

Comment: @torek, yeah. Weird eh?  And I don't know why the question was either. It seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.